# Change song using jquery and <audio>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I've been trying to create a webpage that plays several different songs when the user clicks a button. I've been using the value attribute on buttons to store what the name of the song to send to the audio player. When the button is clicked the song stays as the default, any help would be appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<button value="newsong.mp3">NEW SONG</button>
<audio controls id="player" src="sound/default.mp3" autoplay></audio>
```

**Javascript**

```
var song;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    song=$(this).attr("value");
    $("#player").attr("src","sound/"+song);
    });
  };
});
```

**Edit:** switched names on accident copying code; both ids are player not music

Comment: audio id is `id="music"` and you are using `#player`

Comment: accidentally wrote code down, both should be called player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an extra `};` in your JS code:

```
var song;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    song=$(this).attr("value");
    $("#player").attr("src","sound/"+song);
  });
});
```

### [See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LhHx4/1/)

Comment: thank you! This just made me  realize I had an extra function laying around within the javascript that was creating the error

Answer (score 0):

Audio tag has id `music` and you try to change attribute on tag with id `player`. Since there is no such tag, song will not change.